# Binary to octal conversion. But binary digits are in an array?

Tags: c, binary, octal

//is this correct?

```
#include<stdio.h>  
#include<math.h>
main()  
{  
    int a[1000], n, i,sum=0,b=0,p=0,t=1,c,j=0; 
    printf("Enter the number to convert:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=0; n>0; i++)    
    {    
        a[i]=n%2;    
        n= n/2;  
    }    
    printf("Binary of the given number= ");    
    for(i=i-1 ;i>=0 ;i--)    
    {    
        printf("%d",a[i]); 
        j++;     
    }      
    printf("\n");
    for(c=j-1;c>=0;c--)
    {
        t=pow(8,c)*a[p];
        sum=sum+t;
        p++;
    }
    printf("\noctal %d",sum);
}
//this code is working perfectly till binary conversion but the last for loop is not working properly. Eventhough i think the logic is correct.
```

Comment: your conversion logic isn't as correct as you think. For each bit set in your array `a`, you add a power of 8 to the result. But you need to use 3 bits at once, not just 1.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Representation of numbers are basically strings. There is no decimal, hexadecimal or octal number in memory. They are just values. Octal representation is only for printing. Therefore you should not use integer variables to store your text representation. Use strings instead. As you can only use 8 values per digit instead of 10, you might need more digits than available for an `int` variable.

Comment: First you create an array of binary digits, and then you treat that array of binary digits as if it were an array of octal digits. That is, you convert (for example) three to {1,1}. Then you convert that to eighty-one.

Comment: On side note: don't use `pow`, or other floating-point functions, with problems involving only integers. It's going to cause you many headaches.